# How to change the size of menu item icon in NavigationView?

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

I have the following menu item:

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/lock"
   android:checkable="true"
   android:title="@string/lock" >
   <menu>
       <item
          android:id="@+id/block_mess"
          android:checked="true"
          android:icon="@drawable/chantinnhan"
          android:title="@string/block_mess_string" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/block_call"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/chancuocgoi"
            android:title="@string/block_call_string" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/lock_app"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/khoaungdung"
            android:title="@string/lock_app_string" />
   </menu>
</item>
```

...there's still more but it's really long

but the icon is really small (even it has res 256x256). I'd like to make it bigger! Is this possible?

**Here's the screenshot:**

[image]

EDIT: OK, we both know that Google "lock" the icon size. But I want to know that can I "bypass" that lock and make something... customizable?

Comment: any luck regarding this??? i m stuck also

Comment: @AmanVerma still no luck, buddy :((

Comment: Do we have any example app which has bigger icons than this size? Even Gmail has the same sized icons. What i've heard and read is that the navigationView follows the material design guidelines so the icon sizes match that guideline.

Comment: I require big sized icons too but if we find one example app, maybe we can email the developer and get some knowledge. :)

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib actually you can make a custom drawer. Not really good, but it's customizable.

Comment: Odds are, you can't. I don't know that for sure, but the NavigationView is a very specific design tool made by the Android dev team for a very specific use case, and likely not 100% customizable.

Comment: @ChrisMaverick Yes, It can be customized, but will have to do a lot of work to bring back all the callbacks and UI effects currently being managed by the NavigationView.

Comment: @ChrisMaverick If you've a sample sourcecode, please share. Or maybe some links.

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib hope this can help: http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/

Comment: @ChrisMaverick Have you found a solution yet? I know we can use custom views, but I just wanna know if there's an official way :D

Comment: @Ralphilius there is no official way. Google is pretty strict: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/85080/material-design-icon-size-in-navigation-drawer

Comment: @ChrisMaverick Is it good to override private resource `design_navigation_icon_size` ?

Comment: @Ralphilius can you really do that ? I'm not sure how it works. All I know is design_navigation_icon_size is in OS's framework. And different OSs have different frameworks

Comment: @ChrisMaverick Yes, you can do that. I have tested, but you should override other attributes too for better design.

Comment: @Ralphilius there is still zero answer. But now I think you should make it "count++", sir

Comment: I think you should not put your icon in circle. And icon's size on mdpi should be 24x24 pixel (24dp). Otherwise, android resize them and your icons look bad.

Comment: @wisemann it's not about bad icons or not, it's about "can we make it bigger than 24dp programmatically ?". I actually don't really care if they look bad or not

Comment: just use design_navigation_icon_size

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can change the size of navigationView icon by overriding `design_navigation_icon_size` attribute. You can put it in dimens and because you're overriding a private attribute, you need to include `tools:override="true"`

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>
```

Comment: pretty old question. But it's still a correct answer. Accepted :D

Comment: Is override property setting to true is necessary? Because I think in java user defined properties are having highest value always.

Comment: Without override property settings to true, there will be no changes because android will negate the value.

Comment: But I am not setting override to true also its works.I think because java has highest preference to local than global.

Comment: Is this answer still correct? I am trying this, but I have no success and it always shows the same size in the NavigationView component.

Comment: I just tried it on my code, its still working. Are you using SupportLibrary? Try extends your class to AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Why don't you mention that it needs to be in the dimens file!

Comment: @KishanSolanki124 I did. Read again.

Answer (score 25):

In your xml file the shortest way is there is a property in NavigationView 
Just add it .

`app:itemIconSize="12dp"`

Comment: Awesome! Coincident just answered 4 Hours ago. :D

Comment: I have no idea why only this solution works for me. I am using `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView`

Comment: Thanks. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 23):

**Got Solution**

> Make Below entry in dimens.

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size">48dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 10):

The main thing that decide the icon's size is the dimension:`navigation_icon_size`, have a look at the `NavigationMenuItemView` class:

```
 public NavigationMenuItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.mIconSize = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(dimen.navigation_icon_size);
}
```

so, we can just overide the property in our dimens file.

For example:

```
<dimen name="navigation_icon_size">48dp</dimen>
```

add that code in the dimens file, and you can find it's size changed.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: added, nothing happens !

Comment: It's so werid...I will try to find another way to do that.

Comment: ...it should work in fact,i test it on my phone and genymotion,both work.or mayby you have done somehing wrong about it?

Comment: I just add that "dimen" line in dimes.xml. And I'm using original Navigation Drawer of Android Studio

Comment: Use "design_navigation_icon_size" instead. google added design_ prefix with Support Library 23

Comment: make entry for property name design_navigation_icon_size in dimens and add size in pt it works fine

Answer (score 8):

According to the the design document set by [Google](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#) itself, icons should be set to `14sp`. I suggest you abide by this recommendation, since this is a standard used throughout all apps. As you said, there are no apps which have large icons in the navigation drawer, as this is not the norm when developing a navigation drawer icon.

[image]

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote if this has helped you? Thanks very much :)

Comment: we all know that Google "lock" the icon size. But what I want to ask is can I "bypass" that lock by doing something programmatically....But yeah, an upvote for you :D

Comment: you can try and play with the actual layout xml file for the navigation view, but then again I believe Google lock it to a specific size. So there would be no way to bypass that.

Comment: wondering where in the linked article it's mentioned that icon size should be `14sp`

Comment: Check the specs section