# Sidebar menu with a dynamic size of icons

Tags: android, sidebar

I want to implement a sidebar menu where a user can see all his friends. Therefore the size of my sidebar menu has to be dynamic. Has anyone an idea how I could do that or another method how to implement something similar?

Comment: please add code and screenshots what you want exactly?

Comment: here is a similar question
please see below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179258/how-to-change-the-size-of-menu-item-icon-in-navigationview