# Android set menu icon into small

Tags: android, xml

I have a custom icon here and I want it to become smaller.

This is my xml menu code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:id="@+id/main_page">
        <item

            android:id="@+id/main_page_search"
            android:state_focused="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/magnify"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="Search" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/main_page_check_cart"
            android:icon="@drawable/shopping"
            android:state_focused="true"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="Check cart" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

My xml layout view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set below for each item to for instance 25dp;

android:layout_width and android:layout_height

like

```
<item

        android:id="@+id/main_page_search"
        android:layout_width = "20dp"
        android:layout_height = "20dp"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/magnify"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search" />
```

Comment: ive try taht one sir, no errors found but not working... i did'nt know if my drawable size is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if u want use menu to navigation

> [How to change the size of menu item icon in NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179258/how-to-change-the-size-of-menu-item-icon-in-navigationview?answertab=votes#tab-top)

or you can try customs toolbar and your style set no action bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetStart="16dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

style no action bar like this

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you sir, but this is only for the navigation menu only. you might be check the image i've attach. this will not work on my problem :)

Comment: maybe you can try customs toolbar

Comment: i try this one already and it is working but, i was working with navigation drawer sir, so that i can't configure a custom toolbar.

Comment: why can't configure a custom toolbar?

Comment: like i said sir, i was using navigation drawer os that i cant configure a custom toolbar. though it is possible if i yse empty activity or basic activity.

Comment: okey, you can try add recyclerview in your navigationview. so you just custom your recyclerview